# Bulk insert data in Custom Metadata Type using SFDX cli

Tags: vs-code, custom-metadata, insert, bulk, sfdx-error

I have created a Custom Metadata type in my developer Sandbox.
I want to insert data from csv file using cli in vs code. It is giving me error.

```
sfdx force:cmdt:record:insert --filepath .\Aperia.csv --typename Aperia_PCI_Hierarchy_Mapping__mdt
```

OR

```
sfdx force:cmdt:record:insert --filepath .\Aperia.csv --typename Aperia_PCI_Hierarchy_Mapping
```

**Error:**

> ERROR running force:cmdt:record:insert:  Unexpected arguments: -–filepath, .\Aperia.csv, -–typename, Aperia_PCI_Hierarchy_Mapping__mdt
> See more help with --help

The file name and path is correct and Custom Metadata Type name is also correct.

Comment: it looks like you are using the Custom Metadata's API name for `--typename` parameter, try using the object's name instead.

Comment: Yes, tried that too, showing same error

Comment: do your CSV headers match the field API names from your Custom Metadata Object? Also, you should have one column named `Name` as you are not using the `--namecolumn`

Comment: Yes my CSV file has same headers which are of Field APIs.

Comment: okay then I would suggest making sure you are authenticated to the org where `Aperia_PCI_Hierarchy_Mapping__mdt` is. Also, double check if you have the `Name` column on your csv file, otherwise, specify one using the `--namecolumn` parameter.